# Using PHP Sub String to Link Thumbnails

Tags: php, gallery, substring

So I am making this simple gallery that fetches images from a directory. All images have names like tree_th.jpg and I would like to use sub string (I assume this is correct) to slice out the _th and link out to just tree.jpg

```
<?
    $imagetypes = array("image/jpeg", "image/gif"); 

    function getImages($dir) {
        global $imagetypes; 
        $dir = "img/";
        $retval = array(); 
        if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/"; 
        $fulldir = "/$dir"; 
        //echo $fulldir;
        $d = @dir($fulldir) or die(""); 
    while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) { 
        if($entry[0] == ".") continue; 
        $f = escapeshellarg("$fulldir$entry"); 
        $mimetype = trim(`file -bi $f`); 
        foreach($imagetypes as $valid_type) { 
            if(preg_match("@^{$valid_type}@", $mimetype)) { 
                $retval[] = array( 'file' => "$dir$entry", 'size' => getimagesize("$fulldir$entry") ); 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    $d->close(); return $retval; 
} 

$thumbs = getImages("img"); 
foreach($thumbs as $img) { 
    echo "<img class=\"photo\" src=\"{$img['file']}\" {$img['size'][1]} alt=\"\">\n"; 
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is with str_replace() function in PHP.

`$large_image_path = str_replace("_th","",$thumb_path);`

The substring command you would have to first evaluate the position of the _th, then reassemble the string with a length and concat so I think str_replace would be easier for you.